# Javascript - Receive and format HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, laravel

I have been trying to figure this out of quite a while now. I am building a map (using Google Maps JS API) to display an orbit of a specified satellite. I have been able to achieve some results, none of which take the data from the HTML page, which I want to be able to do. The data is dynamically generated for each page using Laravel Blade with results from my SQL database.

In order to draw an orbit of a satellite I had to use the orbits-js library.

I managed to do this so far:
Take the data from a text file, with the format of:

```
0 ISS (ZARYA)             
1 25544U 98067A   17202.25860705  .00002617  00000-0  46671-4 0  9999
2 25544  51.6406 228.4871 0006083  57.5520  20.0514 15.54198040 67054
```

As you can see, this is the data used to calcuate an orbit. Each line starts with an identifier - 0,1 or 2. This is used by orbit-js to calculate the orbital parameters.

I use this JS code to get the data:

```js
$.get("/other/stations.txt", function(data) {
  stations = orbits.util.parseTLE(data);
  var i = 0;
  for (; i < stations.length; i++) {
    var name = stations[i].name;
    var satOpts = {
      map: map,
      tle: stations[i],
      pathLength: 3,
    };

    var sat = new orbits.Satellite(satOpts);
    sat.refresh();
    sat.refresh_path();
    sats.push(sat);
  }

  setInterval(function() {
    var i = 0;
    for (; i < sats.length; i++) sats[i].refresh();
  }, 500);

  setInterval(function() {
    var i = 0;
    for (; i < sats.length; i++) sats[i].refresh_path();
  }, 5 * 60000);
});
```

The orbits-js library formats the data like this:

```js
orbits.util.parseTLE = function(text) {
  "use strict";
  if (!text || typeof text != "string" || text === "") return [];

  var lines = text.split("\n");

  // trim emepty lines
  for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++)
    if (lines[i] === "") lines.splice(i, 1);

  // see if we got something reasonable
  if (lines.length < 3) return [];
  if (lines.length % 3 !== 0)
    throw new SyntaxError("The number of lines should be multiple of 3");

  // try and make the array
  var three;
  var array = [];
  while (lines.length) array.push(new orbits.TLE(lines.splice(0, 3).join("\n")));

  return array;
};
```

What I want is to take the data from my HTML instead of the txt file. My HTML format is like this:

```html
<li id="tle-data-main">0 ISS (ZARYA)</li>
<li id="tle-data-main">1 25544U 98067A 17198.59697288 +.00000849 +00000-0 +20077-4 0 9991</li>
<li id="tle-data-main">2 25544 051.6415 246.7397 0005882 046.2932 050.6122 15.54169454066485</li>
```

Basically what I need is to modify the JS to take the data from my webpage/HTML and not the txt file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should not have the same id multiple times in your html.
By definition, an id is meant to be unique. Use classes instead :

```
<li class="tle-data-main">0 ISS (ZARYA)</li>
<li class="tle-data-main">...</li>
<li class="tle-data-main">...</li>
```

You want to get the text inside your *.tle-data-main* elements, so you just need to do some jQuery (I saw you're using jQuery).

Instead of your $.get, write :

```
var lines = [];
$('.tle-data-main').each(function() {  // for each element of your class
    lines.push(this.innerText);  // we push a new line containing the text
});
var data = lines.join("\n");  // we join lines to produce text data
stations = orbits.util.parseTLE(data);  // and give it to orbit-js
```